# How to copy a dataset with API

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-embedded, powerbi-datasource

We are building an application which embeds a report as a service principal.
The data source consists of 300 databases so we would like to create 300 datasets.
The structure of these databases is the same so we are able to create 1 dataset with a parameter which points to the database name.

Is it possible to create 1 "template" dataset and copy this one 300 times and change the name and parameter based on the related database name?
So basically what we want to do is duplicate a dataset and change some data inside of it.

We can't seem to find any way to achieve this.